# Speed up wav file reads into np.array, in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, numpy, wav

I need to read hundreds of thousands of short (~1 sec) wav files into either a list or numpy array in Python 3.6. What is the fastest way to do so?

The following code reads at the speed of ~0.8 sec/1000 files (on SSD platform, Windows 2010 64 bit). Anyway to speed it up?

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from timeit import timeit
from numpy import array
wav = ['c:/0.wav']*1000
timeit('a = [read(w)[1] for w in wav]', number=1, globals={'wav':wav, 'read':read, 'array':array})
Out[1]: 0.7742068219069864
```

Here is a [sample wav file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HF1FfNA90Qj0Wd2IobafED8ol7ur02P1).

Comment: I'm not sure if reading a single file multiple times is a good benchmark. It should be cached at some point and what you're measuring is really scipy wav processing performance. If that's the case you might have some benefit with multiple parallel jobs.

Comment: Filippo thanks. That's a lot of assumptions. Is there a faster wav reader/processor?

Comment: You're right about the assumptions. I tried your code on 1000 copies of your wave file (to avoid caching reading the same file) and it runs in 0.5 seconds. If I run it multiple times it reads them from cache and it takes 0.05s. So apparently you're not experiencing caching at all (no idea why, I'm using linux, maybe caching works differently). So, I'd say the bottleneck is the disk and not wave processing.

Comment: Interesting observation. The Python parallel processing is a bit cumbersome to prototype with on a Windows box. Is there a faster alternative to `wavfile.read`?

Comment: Don't know, I'm just blindly guessing, but I think loading many small files is your main performance problem. Most SSDs underperform with this kind of task.